# I'm having a Regex Issues removing & chars

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string

```
../cms/Client Files/gallery images/home1.jpg&w=914&h=360&cache=1:28:02 PM
```

and I want to remove the stuff off the end of the file. In c# I'm trying

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&(w=([0-9]*))", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&(h=([0-9]*))", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&(cache=([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9]*) [AP]M)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

but its not removing anything. If I try

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"w=([0-9]*)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"h=([0-9]*)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"cache=([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9]*) [AP]M", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

then I get

```
../cms/Client Files/gallery images/home1.jpg&&&
```

How can I remove the &'s as well?

Comment: I notice your input string looks a lot like a URL query string, except it is missing the `?`.  Is this intentional?

Comment: Also, to clarify your question, do you want to remove EVERYTHING after the first `&`, or do you just want to remove `w`, `h`, and `cache` items, in case there are additional items?

Comment: @ScottRippy - Yes, this is intentional, no ? just &. I want to remove everything after the first &. But in the example given I dumbed it down. The string(s) that are being modified are imbedded in a one large string (text file really) so I can't just the cut off the end of the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You don't need to escape the **&** to match it](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html), as others have incorrectly suggested.

As a matter of fact, your code works perfectly as you describe!  I just ran your code in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), and verified the results:

```
var html = "../cms/Client Files/gallery images/home1.jpg&w=914&h=360&cache=1:28:02 PM";

html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&(w=([0-9]*))", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&(h=([0-9]*))", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"&(cache=([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9]*) [AP]M)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

html.Dump(); // Outputs: "../cms/Client Files/gallery images/home1.jpg"
```

Therefore, you should inspect the rest of your code and see if another error exists.  This is where a debugger might show you the light.

**Another idea** since your variable is named `html`, is it possible that the `&` is actually encoded as `&amp;`? That might explain things.

**As a side note:**
None of your patterns need the `()`, and they will be simpler without them.

Comment: I'm not at work any more but I will check this again on monday. I'm not sure why I'm seeing the result I am if this is working for you. I'll have to create a test case and post that I suppose. Guess I should've done that in the first place. Its just odd, all my other regex code is working.

Comment: It is possible :-/ Not expected at all, but most certainly possible.

Answer (score 1):

I should try this (easier than using Regex):

```
int index = html.IndexOf("&");
if (index >= 0) html = html.Substring(0, index);
```

or try this:

```
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\&w=([0-9]*)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\&h=([0-9]*)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\&cache=([0-9]*):([0-9]*):([0-9]*) [AP]M", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I can't use this method. I simplified the string I'm using. The full html string is the contents of a html file. I just need to remove these items wherever they are.

Comment: @Justin808 If you don't provide correct input you should also not expect correct answers.

Comment: @Justin808 I am. So you just want to remove everything after first & including &?

Answer (score 0):

This should be enough...

`html = Regex.Replace(html, @"\&.*", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`